# How to replace directory with its constant in a ShellExec line

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have this working line:

```
ShellExec('',ExpandConstant('{app}\iush.exe'),'/ui "C:\Program Files (x86)\Myapp"', ' ', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, errorCode)
```

But i want to replace the Program Files (x86) dirctory with its constant: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Myapp"` >> `{pf32}\Myapp`

Then It would like:

```
ShellExec('',ExpandConstant('{app}\iush.exe'),'/ui "{pf32}\Myapp"', ' ', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, errorCode)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `ExpandConstant` there? You use it with `{app}` but not with `{pf32}`.

Comment: Where can i add the second ExpandConstant?

Comment: I might be wrong. But possible `ExpandConstant({pf32}\Myapp)`. I am sure someone can tell you better than me.

Comment: '/ui {pf32}\Myapp' is the whole parameter I tried: '/ui ExpandConstant({pf32}\Myapp') But it didnt work

Comment: Yeah. You might have to use the ISPP preparser here. I am going to see if someone else can help you.

Comment: I could fix it with: ExpandConstant('/ui "{pf32}\Myapp"') thanks,

Comment: Glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ShellExec('',ExpandConstant('{app}\iush.exe'),ExpandConstant('/ui "{pf32}\Myapp"'),'',SW_HIDE,ewWaitUntilTerminated,errorCode);
```